# Converting a word document to an image

Tags: images, microsoft-word, conversion, documents, capture

Is there any way to convert a Word document to an image? I suppose you can print screen, but that is pretty painful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest way I would think is to install [Bullzip PDF Printer](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php) and then go to the document, print it and change the settings to Image.

Bullzip FAQ -

> Multiple output types supported: BMP, JPEG, PCX, PDF, PNG, and TIFF.

Comment: +1 for decent free PDF software. PDFCreator can also that.

Comment: Easiest and probably the best way, +1.

Comment: another way which maybe is interesting for security guys is doing stenography. hide the word document characters in an image file (except Jpeg) Least significant bit. you can find programs doing this.

Answer (score 3):

What is so painful about a screen shot?

**[Faststone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm)** provides for scrolling screen shots.

**[Version 5.3](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=775)** is free and portable, it doesn't even have to be installed.

[image]

All it takes is pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> in addition to <kbd>PrtScrn</kbd>, you can choose to save the capture as BMP, GIF, JPEG, PCX, PNG, TGA, TIFF or indeed PDF, it doesn't get much easier.

Comment: +1 Because this has the ability to automatically scroll through a full window to screenshot the parts that are not visible!