# Print documents to an image on Windows

Tags: windows, images, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a word document to an image (free)](https://superuser.com/questions/103533/converting-a-word-document-to-an-image-free)

I'm looking for a printer driver that will let me print a multipage document to a **single** image (jpeg, png, whatever) on Windows.

Any suggestions? O:-)